# Getting data from a textbox on windows forms

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm using Visual Studio to make a windows form. I am making a text based survival game for an assignment at university, however I am stuck.

What I am aiming for is for the user to input a selection (`1-4`) into a `textbox` to make their option.

I tried using `4` different buttons, but couldn't seem to get an if statement to work with the button clicks. Then i tried a switch with buttons, then a switch with text and now a textbox with if/else if statements.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;


namespace PF5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int iScore = 0, iChoice;
    String sName;

    public Form1()
    {
        //asks user to input their name before the game begins
        sName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter    your name:", "What is Your Name?", "");
        //if no name is entered, they are asked again
        while (sName == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your name.");
            sName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter your name:", "What is Your Name?", "");
        }


        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //displays the score
        lblScore.Text = iScore.ToString();
        //displays the scoring system in the Rules textbox
        txtRules.Text = "Welcome to SURVIVE,  " + sName + ", during your   time here you will be presented with numerous scenarios and you will be given FOUR options or choices." + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "For each Scenario there will be: " + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "ONE 'Perfect Answer' which will give you +2 points to your score. " + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "ONE 'Correct Answer' which will award you +1 point to your total. " + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "ONE 'Wrong Answer' which will award you +0 points." + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "ONE 'Fatal Answer' which will result in Game Over, Death and -1 point.";
    }


    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Display a message box asking users if they
        // want to exit the application.
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "SURVIVE",
         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
         == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Displays story and Options for the user
        txtStory.Text = "After a heavy night in town, you wake up the following day with the worst headache ever. The night seems to be a blur. The usual business of outside seems to be quiter than normal, even for a Sunday, but you don't think too much about it." + Environment.NewLine + " After you have had a shower, a coffee and got ready you feel slightly better, you turn on the TV to watch your favorite channel, only to see some pandemic on the news, apparently a ZOMBIE OUTBREAK!" + Environment.NewLine + "Luckily for you though, you have played Black Ops Zombies and Minecraft for most of your student life so you know exactly what to do..."
            + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "Option 1: Run outside and ask the first person you see to help you" + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "Option 2: Take some time to get some food and money together and pack them along with extra clothes into your bag." + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "Option 3: Text your friends and see if they are okay." + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "Option 4: Call the police to let them know a Zombie Outbreak is happening";
        btnStart.Visible = false;

            txtChoice.Text = Convert.ToString(iChoice);
            iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if  (iChoice == 1)
            {
                    txtResult.Text = "You run outside and grab the first person you see by the shoulder, apparently this particular person just wanted to chomp on your flesh." + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "YOU DIED!!!";
                    iScore = -1;
                    lblScore.Text = iScore.ToString();
            }
    }
}
}
```

I hope someone can help. I'm pleased with the rest of it, just the if statement `atm`, it just wont detect an entry in the `textbox`, i was also thinking of using a submit answer button, but i have no idea how i would get that to work.

Just worth mentioning that i am not an advanced user (as you can probably tell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see you are using windows forms with textBoxes and buttons, but then you are reading `iChoice` from console. if you have textBox for that variable (`iChoice`) then try this `iChoice = Int32.Parse(iChoiceTextBox.Text);`

change btnStart_click event this way:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Displays story and Options for the user
        txtStory.Text = "After a heavy night in town, you wake up the following day with the worst headache ever. The night seems to be a blur. The usual business of outside seems to be quiter than normal, even for a Sunday, but you don't think too much about it." + Environment.NewLine + " After you have had a shower, a coffee and got ready you feel slightly better, you turn on the TV to watch your favorite channel, only to see some pandemic on the news, apparently a ZOMBIE OUTBREAK!" + Environment.NewLine + "Luckily for you though, you have played Black Ops Zombies and Minecraft for most of your student life so you know exactly what to do..."
            + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "Option 1: Run outside and ask the first person you see to help you" + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "Option 2: Take some time to get some food and money together and pack them along with extra clothes into your bag." + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "Option 3: Text your friends and see if they are okay." + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "Option 4: Call the police to let them know a Zombie Outbreak is happening";
        btnStart.Visible = false;

        iChoice = Int32.Parse(txtChoice.Text);
        if (iChoice == 1)
        {
            txtResult.Text = "You run outside and grab the first person you see by the shoulder, apparently this particular person just wanted to chomp on your flesh." + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "YOU DIED!!!";
            iScore = -1;
            lblScore.Text = iScore.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i forgot to remove the concole readline, that was just an attempt out of desperation, i have been playing with my program since posting and have used an input box identical to the one used for name, and then used an if else statement to detemine the results, this seems to be working so far.